Distributive conditional types not working as expected
I have a couple of complex types that look like this:
type MatchTypeDefault = 'NULL' | 'NOT_NULL';

type MatchTypeBoolean = 'IS';

type MatchTypeText =
    | 'EQUALS'
    | 'EQUALS_CASE_INSENSITIVE'
    | 'NOT_EQUALS'
    | 'NOT_EQUALS_CASE_INSENSITIVE'
    | 'BEFORE'
    | 'AFTER';

type MatchTypeNumber =
    | 'EQUALS'
    | 'NOT_EQUALS'
    | 'GREATER_THAN'
    | 'GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL'
    | 'LESS_THAN'
    | 'LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL';

type MatchTypeArray = MatchTypeDefault | 'INCLUDES' | 'EXCLUDES';

type MatchTypeInArray = MatchTypeDefault | 'IN' | 'IN_CASE_INSENSITIVE';

type OrderParamsOrderBy<T extends {}> = {
    fieldName: keyof T;
    type: 'ASC' | 'DESC';
};

type QueryParamsTopLevel<TObject extends {}> = {
    conditionType: 'AND' | 'OR';
    conditions: GenericQuery<TObject>[];
    fieldName?: never;
    matchType?: never;
    value?: never;
    orderBy: OrderParamsOrderBy<TObject>[];
};

type QueryParamsCondition<
    TObject extends {},
    TKey extends keyof TObject = keyof TObject,
    TMatchType extends
        | MatchTypeText
        | MatchTypeNumber
        | MatchTypeBoolean
        | MatchTypeInArray
        | MatchTypeArray
        | MatchTypeDefault = NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends boolean
        ? MatchTypeBoolean
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends string
        ? MatchTypeText | MatchTypeInArray
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends number
        ? MatchTypeNumber
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends Array<unknown>
        ? MatchTypeArray
        : MatchTypeDefault
> = {
    conditionType?: never;
    conditions?: never;
    fieldName: TKey;
    matchType: TMatchType;
    value: TMatchType extends MatchTypeInArray
        ? string[]
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]>;
    orderBy: OrderParamsOrderBy<TObject>[];
};

export type GenericQuery<TObject extends {}> = {
    [TKey in keyof TObject]:
        | QueryParamsTopLevel<TObject>
        | QueryParamsCondition<TObject, TKey>;
}[keyof TObject];


Problem is this:
When I create a const with that type with a test interface
interface TestType {
    id: string;
    price: number;
    inStock: boolean;
}

const testVariable: GenericQuery<TestType> = {
    fieldName: 'price',
    matchType: 'EQUALS',
    value: 0,
};

It works expected for all MatchTypes (MatchTypeBoolean, MatchTypeNumber, etc.), so based on the typeof the object property given via fieldName (in the example 'price' which is typeof 'number'), I can only set matchType to values of MatchTypeNumber. But when I for example want to match based on a string:
const testVariable: GenericQuery<TestType> = {
    fieldName: 'id',
    matchType: 'EQUALS',
    value: ..., // typeof string | string[]
};

the typeof value is string | string[], which is not wanted. I only want the type of value to be, and only be string[] when matchType is of type MatchTypeInArray.
I've already tried (as you can see) using distributive conditional types in this type here to maybe solve it:
type QueryParamsCondition<
    TObject extends {},
    TKey extends keyof TObject = keyof TObject,
    TMatchType extends
        | MatchTypeText
        | MatchTypeNumber
        | MatchTypeBoolean
        | MatchTypeInArray
        | MatchTypeArray
        | MatchTypeDefault = NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends boolean
        ? MatchTypeBoolean
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends string
        ? MatchTypeText | MatchTypeInArray
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends number
        ? MatchTypeNumber
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]> extends Array<unknown>
        ? MatchTypeArray
        : MatchTypeDefault
> = {
    conditionType?: never;
    conditions?: never;
    fieldName: TKey;
    matchType: TMatchType;
    value: [TMatchType] extends [MatchTypeInArray] // <- HERE
        ? string[]
        : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]>;
    orderBy: OrderParamsOrderBy<TObject>[];
};

but the result is that the type of value will always be string.

• Please consider [edit]ing this code to be a more minimal [mre]. Or at least format it so that it takes up less vertical space. The goal of a [mre] is to demonstrate the issue clearly without distractions (and having to scroll around is a distraction). • If you want to distribute over unions in TMatchType then you need a distributive conditional type (your [TMatchType] is explicitly not distributive) and its scope needs to be the whole object, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks for the quick help! No that fully solved the problem I was having. First time actually asking something on here, so I'm not used to it :)

Another thing I noticed, this type breaks down once a property of the interface is optional. How can I fix that?

"Another thing I noticed" is a followup question, right? I need to see a [mre] before I can begin to answer that, and it belongs in its own question, not comments.

You want your QueryParamsCondition<TObject, TKey, TMatchType> to distribute over unions in TMatchType, right? If so, then one way to do it is indeed with a distributive conditional type, which is necessarily of the form TMatchType extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : ⋯. You tried [TMatchType] extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : ⋯, which is not distributive (the checked type has to be a naked type parameter, see Typescript Distributive Conditional Types for more information). Also, the conditional type has to be scoped to the entire object type, since you want the whole thing to be distributive over unions, not just one property.  So that gives you something like:
type QueryParamsCondition<
  TObject extends {}, TKey extends keyof TObject = keyof TObject,
  TMatchType extends ⋯ = ⋯
> = TMatchType extends any ? {
  conditionType?: never;
  conditions?: never;
  fieldName: TKey;
  matchType: TMatchType;
  value: TMatchType extends MatchTypeInArray ? string[] : NonNullable<TObject[TKey]>;
  orderBy: OrderParamsOrderBy<TObject>[];
} : never;

where you can change that any to unknown or anything you want as long as TMatchType extends it.  Now when you look at GenericQuery<TestType> you'll see that each union member of TMatchType gets its own union member in the output:
type GQT = GenericQuery<TestType>
/* type GQT = QueryParamsTopLevel<TestType> | {
    conditionType?: never;
    conditions?: never;
    fieldName: "id";
    matchType: "EQUALS";
    value: string;
    orderBy: OrderParamsOrderBy<TestType>[];
} | {
    conditionType?: never;
    conditions?: never;
    fieldName: "id";
    matchType: "IN";
    value: string[];
    orderBy: OrderParamsOrderBy<TestType>[];
} | ... */

Playground link to code
